# Setting condition for action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core

I have a table used to track a patient appointments in a clinic.
Check In and out are used to track his presence.
I need to be able to create an appointment **only** if he had checked out

```
    public class Appointment
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Case Number")]
    public virtual string MRN { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Department")]
    public virtual int DepID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Check IN")]
    public virtual DateTime Check_IN { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Check Out")]
    public virtual DateTime? Check_OUT { get; set; }
}
```

I created this method inside the controller to check whether or not he checked out.

```
private bool CheckedOut (string MRN)
{
    return _context.Appointments.Any(a => a.MRN == MRN && !a.Check_Out.HasValue);
}
```

And my `Create` action method.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string MRN, Appointment appointment)
{
    ViewData["MRN"] = MRN;
    if (CheckedOut(appointment.MRN))
    {
        _context.Add(appointment);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Patients");
    }
    return View();
}
```

But the appointment is still created even if the patient has one which he hadn't checked out from.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it create an appointment if the User has checked out?
Because to me it looks like you are checking if any open appointments exist and returning true on that.

should be:

```
    return !_context.Appointments.Any(a => a.MRN == MRN && !a.Check_Out.HasValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem has to be you LINQ query.

i would suggest that you extract variables and set a breakpoint to see what is going on:

```
private bool CheckedOut (string MRN)
{
    var mrn = MRN;
    var hasCheckedOut = a.Check_Out.HasValue;

    return _context.Appointments.Any(a => a.MRN == mrn && !hasCheckedOut);
}
```

Comment: `a.Check_out` will cause a syntax error. And you can get `MRN` value before LINQ without a local variable. Instead, you can try `var appt = _context.Appointments.Where(a => a.MRN == MRN && !a.Check_Out.HasValue).ToList();` and investigate what comes back